# twillio throws AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get' in Django-python

Tags: python, automation, twilio

When I use twilio for whatsapp it recieves the message. But when I tried to send a response with `MessagingResponse` it produces this error. `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'`

The Code I have used is

```
def twillioRequest(request):
    msg = request.POST['Body']
    print(msg)
    
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    resp.message('Ok')
    print(str(resp))
    return str(resp)
```

Until `print(str(resp))` this statement it works fine. This code is deployed in django server and I have connected the twilio with my URL. What is the reason for this error?

Comment: try to return the response without the str. like this: `return resp`

Comment: @KárolySzabó it again returns an another error `AttributeError: 'MessagingResponse' object has no attribute 'get' `

Comment: I see you are using django (some how I missed that on the first look...) I think you should wrap around your answer with `HttpResponse`, import from `django.http`. Use like this: `HttpResponse(str(resp))`. but I have very little experience with django.

Comment: @KárolySzabó Yeah that's right. Thanks for the help. You can provide this as an answer.

Comment: I added as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `HttpResponse`, like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def twillioRequest(request):
    msg = request.POST['Body']
    print(msg)
    
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    resp.message('Ok')
    print(str(resp))
    return HttpResponse(str(resp))
```